# What can cause Chrome saved passwords to fail?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, autofill

Specifically, in a login screen with two visible inputs (a text input for the username, named 'username' and a password type field for the password, named 'password) and two hidden fields (URLs to forward successful resp. faulty requests to after validation), what can cause Chrome to fail to autofill credentials?

If I go to the login screen in Chrome, having previously saved exactly one set of username and password, it mostly autofills the fields correctly. However, every 3-15 times loading the page (apparently more often on a slow connection) it will fail to do that, leaving the fields empty. I've tried attaching events directly in the HTML to listen for change in the fields, but got nothing (literally, the events did not fire).

I use KnockoutJS, but this happens long before ko is activated, or even loaded. I use JQuery 1.7.1 and RequireJS 1.0.5. (Updating them does not seem to affect the problem.)

Are there code patterns known to have this effect? Could it be a weird bug in Chrome? Cosmic radiation?

Comment: Further experimentation places the error as occurring before the DOM load event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by changing the action of the form with JS. If you do so, Chrome will, sometimes, decide this is not the same form at all, and refuse to autofill credentials.

It was hell finding this, so I'm answering this question myself, then maybe some poor soul somewhere can find a solution to their problem here...